# ZF3 - Remove abstract factory of 3rd party module

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

is there a way to extend an abstract factory of a module and remove the extended factory? I have to do some modifications to it, but if I extend it and register my new one, the old factory is still registered, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

You could override factory with your own, but it would lead to code duplication and you would have to monitor updates made by developer of that 3rd party module.

You could use `initializer` but it's invoked during initialization of each service, so it may have impact on performance.

What you are looking is **delegator**. It's kind of wrapper for real(orginal) factory.
Here is excellent article by Marco Pivetta: [Delegator Factories in Zend Framework 2](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-delegator-factories-explained/)
This is how he explains delegators:

> A delegator factory is pretty much a wrapper around a real factory: it
>   allows us to either replace the real service with a "delegate", or
>   interact with an object produced by a factory before it is returned by
>   the Zend\ServiceManager.
>
> In pseudo-code, a delegator-factory is doing following:
>
> service = delegatorFactory(factory());

Example of **Delegator Factory**:

```
class LoggerDelegatorFactory implements DelegatorFactoryInterface
{
    public function createDelegatorWithName(
        ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator,
        $name,
        $requestedName,
        $callback
    ) {
        $logger = $callback();

        $logger->clearFilters();
        $logger->addFormatter(new HttpRequestContextFormatter());

        return $logger;
    }
}
```

Service Manager configuration:

```
'delegators' => [
    'DbLoggingModule\Logger' => [
        'LoggerDelegatorFactory',
        // can add more of these delegator factories here
    ],
],
```